# Magento2: How to include third pary module through composer.json in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, composer

I created a custom module, this module depends on thirt party module(tecnickcom/tcpdf), I added this library in my custom module composer.json file

```
{
"name": "packagename/mymodule",
"description": "N/A",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0",
    "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf":"*"
},
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "2.0.0",
"license": [
    "GPL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Packagename\\Mymodule\\": ""
    }
}

}
```

when i run this composer.json file its create vendor folder in my custom module and download "tecnickcom/tcpdf" library, but it should be in root vendor folder. how can i achieve this.

Comment: You are running composer update in the wrong place. You need to run it from the root magento directory and not from within your module.

Comment: i tried this one also but not getting any result

Comment: Is there a dependency in the main projects composer.json file for your custom module?

Comment: no but how can we add it in root composer.json

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should only run composer install or composer update in the "root project". In your case this is the Magento installation. But since it seems like you did not add your custom module with composer but developing it as part of the root project, its own composer.json has no effect at all.

So, you have to add the requirement on your own. Run this in the Magento root directory:

```
composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf
```

Note that if you publish your module and others install it via composer, this step is not necessary anymore.

Comment: I want to use DOMPDF libs without installed via composer . Let me know best way to setup into my extension.

Comment: @HiteshVaghasiya please post a new question for that , but use the search first. I'm pretty sure there's already a question about third party libraries without composer