# Download depended package after installing module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, composer

I am developing QrCode Extension in Magento2 which is depended [bacon-qr-code] library so I need to download [bacon-qr-code] library using composer.In Magento2 in root composer.json if I add the

```
  "require": {
    "magento/module-offline-shipping-sample-data": "100.1.*",
    "bacon/bacon-qr-code": "1.0.1.*"
},
```

Then it download in vendor folder and I am able to use but what if I provide my Extension to anyone, will he add this line to its main root 
composer.json file ?? Or download the package manually I am little confuse 
please suggest me.I followed this link but did not get clear suggestion.
1:- [Magento2: How to include third pary module through composer.json in custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103188/magento2-how-to-include-third-pary-module-through-composer-json-in-custom-modul)

:-My Module composer.json file

```
    {
    "name": "Ktpl/Relatedprod",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
         "bacon/bacon-qr-code": "1.0.1.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "license": ["GPL-3.0"],
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["registration.php"],
        "psr-4": {
            "Ktpl\\Relatedprod\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you have to first run command of backon qr code, composer require mpyw/co:^1.5

Comment: you have to give recommendation to first install this package using compsoer

Comment: Where should I add this? in root composer.json or in module composer.json file ?

Comment: I added my module composer.json file.

Comment: Is it possible to load libraries using module`s composer.json ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to given documentation for this module,

You can set `readme.txt` file in your module installation.

This is the code for getting Bacon Qr Code in your project.

```
composer require mpyw/co:^1.5
```

Just set hint before installation. so after running above command automatically create folder in magento directory.

If you provide extension with composer command to install your module,
**add require code in composer.json file so when composer update its automatically getting Bacond qr code.**

Comment: I added readme.txt file in my module and paste your code [composer require mpyw/co:^1.5 ] in readme.txt file and run composer update command but unable to add the package in the vendor directory.