# Magento 2 load component composer dependencies

Tags: magento2, composer

I am trying to develop simple Magento 2 module. Accoding to [Composer integration guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/composer-integration.html) I had to put all my dependencies into **composer.json** file into my module root. According to [Default File Structure Guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/prepare/prepare_file-str.html) I had to put my code in **app/code** directory (on development stage, before release). So the question is how to enable magento to load me dependencies from `app/code/vendor-name/package-name/composer.json` file?

1. If I run

> bin/magento setup:upgrade

my module is enabled, but dependencies are not loaded to /vendor

2. If I run

> composer update

from magento root dir, my module dependencies are still not loaded

3. If I run

> composer install

from app/code/[my module dir], dependencies are loaded into app/code/[my module dir]/vendor, but not into [magento root]/vendor dir

What is the best practice for module development with composer dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic mistake we do. composer update will include the module to composer.json and composer.lock **ONLY IF the module is installed by composer.**

In your case you have developed a new module locally which has a composer.json. As your module is not installed by composer it has been manually created in **app/code/** location composer has no track of your newly developed module.

So if your module have a third party dependency you have to use **composer required** command in the Magento root to update the composer.json and composer.lock

```
composer require xyz/abc
```

**Similar post**
[Magento2: How to include third pary module through composer.json in custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103188/magento2-how-to-include-third-pary-module-through-composer-json-in-custom-modul)

Answer (score 0):

First add the dependecy with the defined structure, for example for the dependency  Liquid\Template, note the php -v that you have, and if is compatible.

In my case, 7.1 so https://github.com/kalimatas/php-liquid/releases/tag/1.2.1

Now set the path acording the composer file, in this case will be: vendor/liquid/liquid and all the files go there.
Now edit this 3 files in vendor/composer and add the code.

> installed.json

,
{
"name": "liquid/liquid",
"version": "v1.2.1",
"version_normalized": "1.2.1",
"source": {
"type": "git",
"url": "https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib.git",
"reference": "fc11a53db4b66da555a6a11fce294f574a8374f9"
},
"dist": {
"type": "zip",
"url": "https://api.github.com/repos/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/zipball/fc11a53db4b66da555a6a11fce294f574a8374f9",
"reference": "fc11a53db4b66da555a6a11fce294f574a8374f9",
"shasum": ""
},
"require": {
"php": ">=5.3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
"phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
"predis/predis": "0.8.*@dev",
"squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*",
"symfony/http-foundation": "~2.1"
},
"suggest": {
"ext-openssl": "Allows for usage of secure connections with the stream-based HTTP client.",
"predis/predis": "Allows using the Redis storage backend.",
"symfony/http-foundation": "Allows using the Symfony Session storage backend."
},
"time": "2018-02-14T22:37:14+00:00",
"type": "library",
"extra": {
"branch-alias": {
"dev-master": "0.1-dev"
}
},
"installation-source": "dist",
"autoload": {
"psr-0": {
"OAuth": "src",
"OAuth\Unit": "tests"
}
},
"notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
"license": [
"MIT"
],
"authors": [
{
"name": "David Desberg",
"email": "david@daviddesberg.com"
},
{
"name": "Elliot Chance",
"email": "elliotchance@gmail.com"
},
{
"name": "Pieter Hordijk",
"email": "info@pieterhordijk.com"
}
],
"description": "PHP 5.3+ oAuth 1/2 Library",
"keywords": [
"Authentication",
"authorization",
"oauth",
"security"
]
}

> autoload_namespaces.php

```
    'Liquid\\Unit' => array($vendorDir . '/liquid/liquid/tests'),
'Liquid' => array($vendorDir . '/liquid/liquid/src'),
```

> autoload_static.php

```
,
        'Liquid\\Unit' => 
        array (
            0 => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/liquid/liquid/tests',
        ),
        'Liquid' => 
        array (
            0 => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/liquid/liquid/src',
        ),
```

note in this last file to put the dependency in the right letter.
and it is done!